# How to make sure there is a value in access ComboBox?

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have a form with a ComboBox and a button. when the button is clicked, it's event should check that ComboBox has a value before proceeding.
ComboBox has a default value set:

- Name=cmbName,
- Default Value = "Joe",
- RowSource=`SELECT name
  FROM table
  ORDER BY name;`

This is what I tried:

```
Private Sub btnOk_Click()
    If (CmbName.ListIndex = -1)Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Do Something
End Sub
```

But every time I click the button, `cmbName.ListIndex` does equal -1, and the sub is exited even though there is a default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListIndex is a property of ComboBox. It returns the index of the chosen value in the list. For example: If the first value is selected, `comboBox.listIndex = 0`. If there is no value, then `comboBox.listIndex = -1`.

If the user doesn't select a value from the list, then the value is the default "joe".

If the query `SELECT name
FROM table
ORDER BY name` returns a list in which there is no value "joe", then listIdex will still be -1.

Try:

```
If (CmbName.ListIndex = -1) And (Trim(CmbName.Value & "") = "")
```

Will return true if no value was selected and the box is empty.

Comment: Did you post an answer to your question?

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen, Yes. I tried to make it generic, so that it can help other people.

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen, I will. But the site will only let me do that tomorrow. be patient... (:

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm misunderstanding something; you can just use the [`IsNull()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IsNull-Function-f963233b-1c1e-4b0c-8bc3-3e8c0ea67c61) function.

If the user has changed the value away from the default value, back to a null value, then this will return `True`.

```
Private Sub btnOk_Click()
    If IsNull(CmbName.Value) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Do Something
End Sub
```

Comment: what if he changed it to a value not in the list? Or to an empty value, or to a whitespace character?

Comment: Personally I always ensure the 'Limit To List' property is `True` and that drop-down values are cleansed of whitespace or empty values. If they aren't addressed earlier, then yes you will need to capture those scenarios here.